# How does Python List Slicing X[:, permutation] work

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Not really sure what is happening at [:, permutation] this point.

```
permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
#print(permutation)
shuffled_X = X[:, permutation]
#print(shuffled_X.shape)
shuffled_Y = Y[:, permutation].reshape((1,m))
```

Comment: `X[:, permutation]` is actually calling `X.__getitem__(slice(None, None, None), permutation)`.

Comment: The doubt that I'm stuck with is that, "permutation" is a list with many numbers. So when I write X[:, permutation], which number is it using from the list or how is it even working.

Comment: You aren't slicing a list here, you're slicing a numpy array - which implements a lot of advanced indexing features.  Using a list as an index selects a subset of the array, with indexes given by the list elements.  So to answer "which number is it using": *all of them*.

Comment: What are X and Y, can you specify?

Comment: This question is unclear. But you might benefit from reading a good numpy tutorial; multi-index slicing is very fundamental to numpy.

Comment: Assuming `X` is a (n,m) numpy array, then `X[:, permutation]` just reorders the columns of `X`.  The indexing looks like  `x[:, [1,2,3]]`, where the `:` selects all rows, and the `[1,2,3]` selects specific columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `X` is just a two-dimensional array of size `m x m`

```
X[permutation, :] # permutes the rows of X
X[:, permutation] # permutes the columns of X
X[:, permutation].reshape((1, m**2)) # permutes the columns of X, and reorders X into a row vector
```

````
>>> import numpy as np
>>> m = 5
>>> permutation = list(np.random.permutation(m))
>>> permutation
[3, 2, 4, 0, 1] 
# new row 0 is old row 3
# new row 1 is old row 2
# new row 2 is old row 4
# new row 3 is old row 0
# new row 4 is old row 1
>>> X = np.arange(m**2).reshape((m,m))
>>> X
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
>>> X[permutation,:]
array([[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9]])
>>> X[:,permutation]
array([[ 3,  2,  4,  0,  1],
       [ 8,  7,  9,  5,  6],
       [13, 12, 14, 10, 11],
       [18, 17, 19, 15, 16],
       [23, 22, 24, 20, 21]])
>>> X[:,permutation].reshape((1,m**2))
array([[ 3,  2,  4,  0,  1,  8,  7,  9,  5,  6, 13, 12, 14, 10, 11, 18,
        17, 19, 15, 16, 23, 22, 24, 20, 21]])```
````